# как подключить rootViewController без использования XIB и StoryBoard?

Tags: objective-c

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    CGRect firstFrame = CGRectMake(16, 240, 100, 150);
    HypnoView *firstView = [[HypnoView alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:firstView];

    // вот тут вылазит ошибка, если я не подключаю firstView то получаю
    // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
    // 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows 
    // are expected to have a root view controller at the end 
    // of application launch'

    self.window.rootViewController = firstView;

    // а если пишу эту строку то у меня черный экран и 
    // reason: '-[HypnoView _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: 
    // unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x797131e0'

    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Где ошибка? И что надо исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    application.statusBarHidden = YES;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```